# Active Directory Trusted Relation

Tags: active-directory

If we have a trusted relationship between two domains, an administrator user of the domains (1) have the administration privileges in the other domain (2)?

Or this only occurs if someone in the domain (1) give to this user de administrator privileges?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi since you do not wrote what Kind of forest you use please give US more Information.

Comment: It is an organizational forest with two-way trust